# How to display user profiles in Joomla 1.6?

Tags: php, joomla1.6

I need to display user profiles in Joomla 1.6.

Is there a default way to do that (url based with user id) or do I need to install an Extension or Plugin?

I hope it to be something like that: index.php?option=com_users&user_id=42

The question is not much about programming, but maybe someone can give me a hint :)
Thanks for looking at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Comment: I created a hack myself, should work for this use case. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to create a profile plugin, and enable the "User - Contact Creator".  As well, configure the contacts component to "show profile"

This way,  your user profiles appear in a contact - which can be listed.  Additionally, the Joomla router gives it a pretty address which includes the name of the user:

http://www.yoursite.com/users/3-michael-richey.html

The id prepended to the name in the URL isn't the user id, but the contact id.  So it adds some security in that the actual user id isn't revealed in the URL.

Other things, of course, must be done to achieve an adequate level of pretty in the output - but this is the way to start without altering the core.